# base64 codec for use with pipe in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, base64

Powershell can access a base64 codec through the
`[System.Convert]::{From,To}Base64String()` functions.
However, these take a string which besides being clunky
to use limits their use with streamed data or larger inputs
in general.

Does a vanilla Windows installation offer an alternative
that can be used in a pipe? I’m looking for something like
coreutils *base64(1)* that can be fed input through stdin
and writes to stdout:

```
$ base64 -d <foo.ascii |frobnicate |base64
```